# Accessing a corrupt WordPress Admin Panel

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

So long story short, the development company that built out this website has left one of my small clients without communication or help at all and have completely ghosted them (Terrible business practice)..

**Problem**:
I have the credentials for the admin panel and had access before, but **I DO NOT** have access to FTP at all - This was never provided.

Website for reference: http://innovativebrokerage.demo.globalwebdesign.com/wp-admin/

The problem is that a plugin auto updated it looks like and has corrupted the whole website and I can't even gain access to the admin panel (wp-admin) to disable the plugin or look into the error as shown below:
[image]

Is there a way that I can access the wp-admin panel in debug mode? Other alternatives? I've tried it all and without the FTP access, I can't seem to figure out what else to attempt.

Comment: What version of wp are you using? An update to the latest version might solve the problem but before updating you will need to ensure that the correct versions of php and mysql are being used.

Comment: This really isn't the place for this kind of question, but if you have access to the mysql database, you may be able to disable the plugin from there. eg wp_options -> active_plugins

Comment: Thanks guys, thats understandable - Was just wondering and feel free to delete this question if it doesn't follow guidelines - I don't have access to either FTP nor MySQL - Looks like I'll have to harass the development company until something is provided.